# Font face permission check error in server

Tags: html, css, fonts, webfonts

```
 <style>
  @font-face {
font-family: "Lithos Pro Regular";
src: url('Fonts/LithosPro-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('Fonts/LithosPro-Regular.eot'),
     url('Fonts/LithosPro-Regular.woff') format('woff'), 
     url('Fonts/LithosPro-Regular.ttf')  format('truetype'),
     url('Fonts/LithosPro-Regular.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
}
 .QuestionNumber {
width: 15px;
height: auto;
float: left;
position: relative;
top: 58px;
left: 30px;
font: 20px "Lithos Pro Regular";
color: #362e2b;
  }
 </style>
 <p class="QuestionNumber "></p>
```

Hi All,
      I have been using **"Lithos Pro Regular"** font for my webpage. the above font works well in all the browsers including IE8. Even when i run my webpage on my localhost it renders well. But when i deploy my webpage in the DEVINT Server [Development & Intergration Server] it is showing **CSS3114: @font-face failed OpenType embedding permission check. Permission must be Installable**  error... I have been trying to find a solution to overcome this problem but failed to find any.
            Is it a problem of the font file or Server configuration is required ?? Can you please help me out.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Check this post if it helps http://codecanyon.net/forums/thread/css3114-fontface-failed-opentype-embedding-permission-check-permission-must-be-installable/78963

Comment: Thanks, I checked that post.. what should be done ?? Does it require server config ??

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling it's because that font can't be used that way. The web font license for this particular font is only available at [Typekit](https://typekit.com/fonts/lithos-pro) which uses an import technique in your head.

In other words, to run it through a web-font generator would be illegal (and this embedding error is quite common when used with Font Squirrel's engine).

Comment: If you really have to use Lithos Pro Regular, you are going to need to get a Typekit account and a subscription for the font license.

Comment: does is it cost ? if so i need some other feasible solution

Comment: If you have an Adobe Cloud subscription it's included. Otherwise you'll have to pay. If you don't want to pay for the license you'll need to use a different font.

Comment: sadly i dont have Adobe cloud subscription. which tool is the best for converting ??
suggest some links. i'll try in that

Comment: There is no legal alternative. I'm not going to suggest anything illegal.